# Substitution in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, substitution

Hi I am kind of confused about substitution in Ocaml.

I know something like v[15/v] would evaluate to 15 because it is replacing all free variable in the expression v, but for a function like fun v -> v [15/v], what would the answer be? would it be fun v -> 15? or simply fun v -> v, because I thought fun v -> v is a closed expression, so there is no free variable in it.

Answer (score 4):

It's true, `fun v -> v` has no free variables. So there are no variables to substitute, and the result should be `fun v -> v`.

Another way to look at it is that the `v` in `fun v -> v` is a new `v`. It's not the same `v` you're wishing to substitute for. So there's no substituting to do.

(I don't know anything about the formalisms you're working with, but it seems like things have to work this way in any reasonable system. I hope I'm right :-)